# buckets list is empty with @google-cloud/storage, however, gcloud list is full

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to get download reports from Play Console using nodejs, permissions and everything else seems to be correct but I can't get list the buckets or their files using @google-cloud package.

I can list and get everything using `gcloud storage ls`

```
const storage = new Storage({
  keyFilename: process.env.GCP_APP_KEY,
});

async function listBuckets() {
  const [buckets] = await storage.getBuckets();

  console.log('Buckets:', buckets.length);
  buckets.forEach(bucket => {
    console.log(bucket.name);
  });
}

listBuckets().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: What is printed for buckets.length and bucket.name?

Comment: it's zero.
I've found that the issue is that the Play Console bucket is not associated to any Project, I cant find a way to see it then

Answer (score 0):

Try adding projectId as same as project id you see in cloud dashboard

Comment: tried and nothing changed, also, project-id is on the gcp json file I'm using to create the storage (keyFilename)

Comment: you need to check if the profile has permission to do that

Comment: It does have permission, I had permissions error and fixed by adding to the profile: "Storage Admin"