# How to access a bucket outside a project (global) with nodejs and @google-cloud?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Our Play Console bucket URI is not associated with any project. Therefore, I cannot access it using any library since the library permission must be assigned to a project.

Is there any way I can move the bucket to a project?

Please note, that creating a new bucket inside the project_id won't solve the issue, I need to access that URI bucket, because it is the App download Reports from the Play Store Console.

Asked here:
[buckets list is empty with @google-cloud/storage, however, gcloud list is full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77500350/buckets-list-is-empty-with-google-cloud-storage-however-gcloud-list-is-full)

Comment: No, you cannot move the bucket. 2) Go to the Google Cloud Project associated with your Google Play account. Then add the service account identity to IAM granting permission to the bucket.

Comment: @JohnHanley the bucket is not associated with any project: https://imgur.com/SLXw9pp

Comment: Go to your Google Play project. Is the bucket visible there? I have never seen an orphan bucket that you can access. You might need Google Cloud support (paid) to resolve this.